# Image gradient (shaprness) and variance of laplacian (focus) values change with camera of different phones for blur detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, photoshop, blur

I aim to flag if the image captured is blurred. For this I have tried out two methods using opencv and intend to use threshold for deciding if image is blurred :
1. Variance of laplacian using following:

```
Imgproc.Laplacian(src_gray_image, dest_lap_image, CvType.CV_16S,3,1,0);
Core.meanStdDev(dest_lap_image, mean , std);
var of laplacian = Math.pow(std.get(0,0)[0],2);
```

2. Gradient in image in x and y directions:

   Imgproc.Sobel( image, Gx, CvType.CV_32F, 1, 0 );
   Imgproc.Sobel( image, Gy, CvType.CV_32F, 0, 1 );
   double sumSq = normGx * normGx + normGy * normGy;
   gradient = (float)( 1. / ( sumSq / image.size().area() + 1e-6 ));

These values differ at lot when same scene is captured with different mobile phones.
**E.g** laplacian variance = 79 for camera1 and 5000 for camera2
gradient value = 2*10-4 for camera1 and 4*10-5 for camera2.

Following are the meta data:
**camera1:**
4096x2304
Exposure time: 1/17
Aperture value: 1.53
ISO speed: 121
Focal length: 4.0

**camera2:**
1456x2592
Exposure time: 1/50
Aperture Value: 2.53
ISO: 160
Focal length: 3.5mm

What I am not able to understand is ,
1.  what values of camera decides on sharpness and focus and how does it affect the gradient and laplacian variance values because these values are the features that ideally must me camera independent. 
2. How do we calculate these values so that they are device independent.
3. Is there any other method to do a quick basic blur detection that does not depend on image meta data.